# Facebook response API not working in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am creating a web app in codeigniter with facebook login, and while sending I have created a API Key and also a response `redirect_uri`.

The problem here is while executing the project in the separate file, it's working fine, but when I was trying to integrate to my project. Facebook is asking for permission to enter to the app that's working fine. But the problem is I'm not getting any response from Facebook to display values and store it in the database.

The code which I was sing in my project is shown below.
Codeigniter coding format

```
application
   /----config
        /----facebook.php // "contains the appId & secret Key"
   /----controller
        /----book_your_service.php //"contains the facebook_request & facebook_response"
   /----libraries
        /----Fbconnect.php //contains the URL send and Response
        /----facebook  "Library file downloaded from github"
             /----facebook.php
             /----base-facebook.php
```

Following code is for libraries --> Fbconnect.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

include (APPPATH.'libraries/facebook/facebook.php');

class Fbconnect extends Facebook
{
  public $user = NULL;
  public $user_id = NULL;
  public $fb = false;
  public $fbSession = false;
  public $appkey = 0;

  public function Fbconnect(){

    $ci =& get_instance();
    $ci->config->load('facebook', TRUE);
    $config = $ci->config->item('facebook');
    parent::__construct($config);

    $this->user_id = $this->getUser();

    //print_r($this->user_id);
    $me = null;
    if($this->user_id){
      try{
        $me = $this->api('/me');
        //echo $me;
        $this->user = $me;
      }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        error_log($e);
      }

    }
  }
}
```

the following code used in book_your.php for sending and receiving the response from facebook.

```
// Facebook Login API Code
  public function facebook_request()
  {
    $this->load->library('fbconnect');
    $data = array(
      'redirect_uri' => site_url('book_your_service/facebook_response'),
      'scope' => 'email'
    );
    redirect($this->fbconnect->getLoginUrl($data));
  }
  public function facebook_login()
  {
    //session_start();
    $this->load->library('fbconnect');
    if($this->fbconnect->user){
    echo"<pre>";
    print_r($this->fbconnect->user);
    echo"</pre>";
    }else{
    echo "Could not connect this time";
    }
  }
```

The facebook Bundle which I was using in this project is shown below 
https://github.com/puneetkay/Facebook-PHP-CodeIgniter.git

Comment: That uses the PHP SDK v3, which is _very_ old - current is v5. I’d suggest that you find a framework that uses the current SDK. Other than that, you’ll have to delve deeper into what is actually happening, and debug through the code to see where exactly it fails.

Comment: The best and official way of using facebook API is by downloading it by using composer. I made a detailed tutorial on facebook SDK v5 integration in CodeIgniter in my blog. You can refer  if you want by visiting following link http://shareurcodes.com/blog/facebook%20php%20sdk%20v5%20with%20codeigniter

Comment: Thanks for reply. The Version which I was using for this project is codeigniter 2.2.0, why I was trying in older version is becoz, It's already completed in older version of codeigniter. the only thing remaining is social login that's why I was trying to complete it in older version.